Jenkins Docker Agent Stuck "Offline" Despite Image Being Available Locally
I'm setting up a Jenkins master on an EC2 instance and am trying to use Docker to spin up agents based on a specific image for my builds. I’ve configured everything according to the documentation, but I’m encountering a problem: Jenkins attempts to use the Docker agent but keeps it in an “offline” state, and the build is stuck on “Still waiting to schedule task.” Here are the details:
Setup:

Jenkins Master: Running on an EC2 instance (Amazon Linux, using yum for package management).
Docker: Installed and configured on the EC2 instance, and I’ve confirmed that the Jenkins user is in the Docker group.
Docker Image: The required image (docker-python) is already pulled locally on the EC2 instance. I am using devopsjourney1/myjenkinsagents:python

Jenkins Configuration:

In Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes and Clouds > Configure Clouds, I added a Docker cloud with a Docker Agent Template using the docker-python label and specified the docker-python image.
In the Jenkinsfile, I specify the agent like this:

pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'docker-python'
        }
    }
    // additional stages...
}



I’ve also installed the Docker plugins in Jenkins to enable Docker agent functionality.

Problem:
When I run the build, Jenkins logs show a message like this:
Still waiting to schedule task
All nodes of label ‘docker-python’ are offline

It appears that Jenkins recognizes the label and attempts to provision a Docker agent, but it remains offline, and the build doesn’t proceed.
Additionally, the Built-In Node on Jenkins displays (I don't know if it's helpful):
Disk space is below threshold of 1.00 GiB. Only 470.34 MiB out of 474.74 MiB left on /tmp.

NOTE:
I am running on a free tier.
Any help would be appreciated!

If by "the docker-python image" you mean this one then the problem is that it doesn't have java installed, so Jenkins cannot start an agent there. The docker plugin actually warns you that java is required when you are configuring the templates. You might have better luck with Jenkins agent images, like this python one. But then again, you might not. If you are on the latest LTS Jenkins then you are already on Java 17 and the official agents are still on Java 11. Your best bet is making your own image. Add the right Java version, the tools you need, put it on ECR, and it should work.
